# Join alias not used into CASE WHEN on SELECT close

Tags: sql, sql-server, hibernate, hql, jpql

Consider these three entities:

```
@Entity
public class EntityA {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    
    @JoinColumn(updatable=false, name="entityB_id")
    @OneToOne
    private EntityB entityB;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="entityParent")
    private Set<EntityAggregated> entitiesAggregated = new HashSet<>();
}
```

And:

```
@Entity
public class EntityB {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="entityB")
    private EntityA entityParent;
}
```

Then:

```
@Entity
public class EntityAggregated {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    private EntityA entityParent;

    private BigDecimal amount;
    
}
```

It seems that SQL generated is wrong (for SQL Server):

```
SELECT entityA.id,
      (CASE WHEN entityBAlias IS NOT NULL THEN entityBAlias.id ELSE -1 END),
      SUM(entityAggregated.amount)
FROM EntityA entityA
   LEFT JOIN entityA.entityB entityBAlias
   LEFT JOIN entityA.entitiesAggregated entityAggregated 
GROUP BY entityA.id, entityBAlias.id
```

SQL Generated is:

```
SELECT e1_0.id,
       CASE
         WHEN e1_0.entityb_id IS NOT NULL THEN e2_0.id
         ELSE -1
       END,
       Sum(e3_0.amount)
FROM   entitya e1_0
       LEFT JOIN entityb e2_0
              ON e2_0.id = e1_0.entityb_id
       LEFT JOIN entityaggregated e3_0
              ON e1_0.id = e3_0.entityparent_id
GROUP  BY e1_0.id,
          e2_0.id
```

That cause an error in SQL Server, because `e1_0.entityb_id` is not in the group by clause :

> org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: JDBC exception executing
> SQL [select e1_0.id,case when e1_0.entityB_id is not null then e2_0.id
> else -1 end,sum(e3_0.amount) from EntityA e1_0 left join EntityB e2_0
> on e2_0.id=e1_0.entityB_id left join EntityAggregated e3_0 on
> e1_0.id=e3_0.entityParent_id group by e1_0.id,e2_0.id] [Column
> 'EntityA.entityB_id' is invalid in the select list because it is not
> contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.]
> [n/a]

Because `CASE WHEN e1_0.entityb_id IS NOT NULL` should be `CASE WHEN e2_0.id IS NOT NULL` (it works like that on versions below 6.0)

However, if HQL test is: `CASE WHEN entityBAlias.id` instead of `CASE WHEN entityBAlias`, it works.

**I think it's a bug because in CASE WHEN, alias `entityBAlias` is used, not `entityA`, then, the CASE WHEN should test on `entityBAlias` into generated SQL.**

Comment: There is no aggregation at all so you should not be using group_by.

Comment: Not in this example but if I want to use aggregation, It doesn't work, the problem is the same. I do not aggregation in this case to have simplier query example but in my project there is aggregation.

Comment: I think it's a bug, in your code :D you can't introduce random columns in group by without adding them there as well

Comment: As you want: I added table to make an aggregation and the problem is still there. @siggemannen It's not 'random columns', it's columns at all. I found this problem on complex query that I cannot put there so I reproduce It with simpliest tables possible. It's just an example to explain problem

Comment: what i mean is, if you add a column to select outside of the aggregate function, you need to add it to group by too, but you don't in the hql.

Comment: @siggemannen I'm not sure to understand you: I always added columns in GROUP BY even in HQL, otherwise  it doesn't work with SQL Server. 
With **hibernate 5**, this hql: `CASE WHEN entityBAlias IS NOT NULL` works fine and column tested is primary key of LEFT JOIN alias: `entityBAlias.id` but **with hibernate 6**, test is on foreign key:  `EntityA.entityB_id`.
For me it's obvious that if I write `CASE WHEN entityBAlias IS NOT NULL`, then sql should be `CASE WHEN entityBAlias.id IS NOT NULL` instead of `CASE WHEN entityA.entityB_id IS NOT NULL`

Comment: The only bug I see is in your post (you fix your bug in your last comment) : you should clearly begin your post that it worked in v5 not in v6. Even if v6 is big new release (breaking change) such a simple query should be correctly optimized and it seems it is not. I think there is many problems in query optimization in v6 I doubt if this is caused by this fix https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/pull/6504